# [R6]Error in as.vector(x, "symbol") : cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'symbol'

Tags: r, r6

I use my R6 object and funcion in the following code

```
Test = R6Class(
  "test",

  public = list(
    y_name = NA,

    initialize = function(y_name){
      self$y_name = y_name
    }

  )
)

someAnalysis = function(tbl, y_name = "y_name", y = "a", test = Test$new("y")){
   tbl = tbl %>%
    filter(!!as.name(y_name) == y)

   print(test$y_name)
   print(tbl$y_name)
}
```

In some case, it is done successfully.

```
someAnalysis(tbl)

[1] "y"
[1] "a"
```

However, the error occurs in the following code

```
test = Test$new("y")
someAnalysis(tbl, test)
Error in as.vector(x, "symbol") : 
  cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'symbol'
```

Why does error occur when defining the Test object outside of function?

Please tell me how to avoid error in using Test class and someAnalysis method

Comment: You’re passing your R6 object to the y_name parameter.

Comment: Actually, I know. My original class and function ,which show the above error, are complicated, so I extract essential parts of my codes.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are making a new object:

```
test = Test$new("y")
```

Here you are passing that object to the parameter `y_name`, not the parameter, `test`:

```
someAnalysis(tbl, test)
```

Here `as.name` is expecting an object that can be coerced to a character vector:

```
tbl = tbl %>%
 filter(!!as.name(y_name) == y)
```

But in your call `y_name` is being passed your R6 object, which is of type `environment`. Hence your error.

Comment: Thank you very much.I'm sorry for misunderstand my codes and your advice. I will be careful in posting